# SAAS option that acts like a web browser in a browser?

Tags: web-browser, proxy, saas

I recently moved a service that manages VMs into an AWS VPC, so all of the servers are in the cloud but not directly internet accessible. We access them with Apache Guacamole, so users can get to the servers through one access point but cannot reach the servers directly. My lab users install our application that we support, which is a web based service and they can use it on those servers directly, but there are limitations (no audio for playback, for example).

I want to find a service that works similarly to Guacamole but for displaying the web page. I've tried a reverse proxy setup, so https://proxy.example.com/lab1 routes to the internal lab page of https://lab1.vpc.local, but it fails because of hostname validation and other issues.

What I'd be looking for is a web-based service that acts like a web browser on the external server that can browse on the internal side of things using the internal domain names, and so far I am not having much luck finding something like this. Does anyone have recommendations of a service that would accomplish this?

Comment: your question is not clear. if a user can open Guacamole to the server, they should be able to run a web browser on that server. what prevents them from doing that?